# 401 error with jwt token using newest okta-spring-boot-starter 2.1.2 with spring boot 2.5.6

Tags: spring-boot, okta

using these dependency versions in an api for jwt access validation:

```
<okta-spring-boot-starter.version>2.1.2</okta-spring-boot-starter.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.5.6</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

I am getting problems with jwt tokens.  the gui we are using is react with @okta/okta-react 6.  it throws errors  (401) authenticating jwt tokens when calling api that uses the above versions.

If we change back to okta-spring-boot-starter 2.0.0, it works. any ideas?

our security config looks like this for the jwt part:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
```

...

```
 @Order(2)
  @Configuration
  public static class NormalSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(ANT).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(withApi(ANT)).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

  Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
}
```

Comment: Turn up the logging: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`
That should help narrow down the issue.
How is your Spring Boot application configured?  Do you have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` if so, what does it look like?

Comment: Looks like you created a GitHub issue: https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/360
We can keep the conversation going over there instead of on SO.

Comment: @Iggs
Any workaround for this? I'm facing the same issue. After increasing the okta-spring-boot-starter version to 2.1.6 Apis start to throw 401 exceptions even with a valid token. But issue is resolved when I downgraded it to 2.0.0 or lower.